# How to use extended ASCII characters in the lstlisting environment?

Tags: input-encodings, extended-characters, ascii

When using extended ASCII characters inside the lstlisting environment, i.e. those corresponding to codes 191 - 197 (literally: ┐, └, ┴, ┬, ├, ─, ┼), latex produces the following error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\lst@EC�\lst@EC� (U+2832C0)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. ├──
```

Is there any way to enable the use of such characters inside lstlisting? Using `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` instead of `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Do they work outside of a `listlisting` environment? In normal text, in `\texttt`, in a `verbatim` environment?

Comment: does `\usepackage{pmboxdraw}` help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `pmboxdraw` and the `literate` key for `listings`. In the documentation for `pmboxdraw` there is the full list with the LICR names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,pmboxdraw}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces,
  literate=
  {┐}{\textSFiii}1%
  {└}{\textSFii}1%
  {┴}{\textSFvii}1%
  {┬}{\textSFvi}1%
  {├}{\textSFviii}{1}%
  {─}{\textSFx}1%
  {┼}{\textSFv}1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
a b c d e f g
┐ └ ┴ ┬ ├ ─ ┼
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: {│}{\textSFxi}1% is useful too. Great answer, it saved my day and cups of coffee.