# (SOLVED) listings, utf8, ├─, (U+2500)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: pdftex

I have the following MWE, and I get the output I wish, but for a single trick: i need to have some extra '\' in front of the worrysome characters '├─ ', '│', ecc.. Without the '\' in front, things are rendered all messed up. 
Questions are: why so?  is there a quick fix?

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
% \usepackage{listingsutf8}  <--- Not needed
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{pmboxdraw}  <--- Needed

\lstset{
    language=bash,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,
    numbers=left,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    frame=single,
    tabsize=2,
    rulecolor=\color{black!30},
    literate=
{│}{\textSFxi}1%
{┐}{\textSFiii}1%
{└}{\textSFii}1%
{┴}{\textSFvii}1%
{┬}{\textSFvi}1%
{├}{\textSFviii}{1}%
{─}{\textSFx}1%
{┼}{\textSFv}1, 
    title="My Folder",
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
%   breaklines=true,
%   breakatwhitespace=true,
    framextopmargin=2pt,
    framexbottommargin=2pt,
    extendedchars=false,
%   inputencoding=utf8
    commentstyle=\mycommentstyle,
    escapechar=\$,
}
\newcommand{\mycommentstyle}[1]{\normalfont\rmshape{ $\leftarrow $ #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\ ├── jsdom_demo-master       $\mycommentstyle{I need normal font here}$
\ │   ├── dummy.html
\ │   ├── jquery-1.7.1.min.js
\ │   ├── README.md
\ │   └── transform.js
1 directories, 4 files
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

EDIT ABOVE FIXEX IT! THANKS TO WHOEVER MADE A COMMENT

Comment: Interesting question. Note that any character works, not just \ (if you put *a* in front of every line it also works).

Comment: Your call to `\usepackage{listingsutf8}` is doing nothing: per the package manual, `listingsutf8` only modifies the `listinputlisting` environment and does not change the `lstlisting` environment you are using. Your UTF8 character therefore is just breaking the `listings` package exactly like the author say it would on page 15 of the manual.

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464711/4427?

Comment: egreg:  I see, thanks, it fixes it; Willie: yes, you are correct, thanks

Comment: Good question! For future reference, it’s better to self-answer than to edit your own question so that it no longer demonstrates the original problem.